# WITH clause with FUNCTION AND PROCEDURE, where is the mistake?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table 'Studies' (with columns: student_id, name, surname, course_name, mark) and I have a task to write a PL/SQL program, where will be WITH word + FUNCTION word + PROCEDURE word.I decided to make such a program: the function will calculate the average mark for some course (input parameter) and the procedure will display information about students whose mark in this course is higher than the average. I managed to create a function that returns the average score,

```
create or replace FUNCTION average_mark(co_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN REAL IS
  iter NUMBER := 0;
  aver NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT mark
    FROM studies
    WHERE course_name = co_name;
BEGIN
  FOR student IN c1
  LOOP
  iter := iter + 1;
  aver := aver + student.mark;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN ROUND((aver/iter),2);
END above_average_mark;
```

and procedure which displays information about a student whose mark in the course is more than a certain one, how now to connect the procedure and the function and the WITH word?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE above(co_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
  CURSOR c2
  IS
    SELECT *
    FROM studies
    WHERE course_name = co_name;
BEGIN
  FOR student IN c2
  LOOP
  IF (student.mark > 4) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('name: ' || student.student_name || ', mark: ' || student.mark);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

i need something like this:
WITH
PROCEDURE
FUNCTION

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your tables to illustrate it, so I'll use Scott's sample schema to calculate average salaries for departments.

As you said that *you need something like WITH PROCEDURE FUNCTION*, the only thing you have to do is to follow syntax.

Therefore, here you are: `with` factoring clause in this example contains a procedure which displays department name and average salary; function calls the procedure (and passes department number and average salary it calculated). Also, as any other function it actually *returns* a value.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> with
  2    procedure p_deptno (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type,
  3                        par_avgsal in number)
  4    is
  5      l_dname dept.dname%type;
  6    begin
  7      select dname into l_dname
  8      from dept
  9      where deptno = par_deptno;
 10      dbms_output.put_line('Average salary for department ' || l_dname ||
 11                           ' = ' || par_avgsal);
 12    end p_deptno;
 13
 14    function f_avgsal (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
 15    return number
 16    is
 17      l_avgsal number;
 18    begin
 19      select round(avg(e.sal)) into l_avgsal
 20        from emp e
 21        where e.deptno = par_deptno;
 22
 23      p_deptno (par_deptno, l_avgsal);
 24
 25      return l_avgsal;
 26    end f_avgsal;
 27  select f_avgsal (a.deptno) avg_sal
 28  from dept a;
 29  /
```

Result:

```
   AVG_SAL
----------
      2917
      2175
      1567


Average salary for department ACCOUNTING = 2917
Average salary for department RESEARCH = 2175
Average salary for department SALES = 1567
Average salary for department OPERATIONS =
SQL>
```

---

Now, adjust it to your tables & data.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try, I wrote the table structure at the very beginning.

DROP TABLE Studies;

CREATE TABLE Studies (

Student_id VARCHAR(5),

Student_name VARCHAR(50),

Student_surname VARCHAR(50),                                                              

Course_name VARCHAR(50),
Mark INTEGER);

Comment: You're welcome. True - you listed columns in these two tables, but without CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data so I'd have to create tables myself and get *nothing* as a result

Comment: Here is CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO, https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/b71321ed90fb9f219acff8c1742afa78/  help please change you code,

Comment: https://notepad.ltd/mezpt42j
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows